# Function to return many values in one column based on multiple queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am about to a build a notification feature
The app is a car ads website
The dealer inserts car ads
The visitor Could save searches as string (URL)

```
---------------------------------------------------------
saved_search_id|visitor_id |search_url
---------------------------------------------------------
0              | 1         |type=0&price_max=10000&color=red
1              | 1         |type=2&price_max=15000&color=black
2              | 2         |type=3&price_max=20000&color=white
```

Whene the dealer inserts a new car, i parse all saved searches into SQL queries

```
//array(arrays(saved_search_id, saved_search_query))
array(
  array(0, "EXISTS(SLECT car_id FROM Car WHERE type=0 AND price <= 10000 AND color = red)"),
  array(1, "EXISTS(SLECT car_id FROM Car WHERE type=2 AND price <= 15000 AND color = black)"),
  array(2, "EXISTS(SLECT car_id FROM Car WHERE type=3 AND price <= 20000 AND color = white)")
)
```

For each saved_search_query i check Whether the new car is included in search result or not. if yes, i send an Email to notify the visitor
i can't figure out how to build one query that returns relevant saved_search_id … instead of running all queries one by one (thousands of Saved searches)
Below is the closest expression to what i am trying to translate

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_saved_search_id(query, id){
  if(query){
    return id;
  }
}    
SELECT get_saved_search_id('EXISTS(SLECT car_id FROM Car WHERE type=0 AND price <= 10000 AND color = red)', 0)
UNION
SELECT get_saved_search_id('EXISTS(SLECT car_id FROM Car WHERE type=2 AND price <= 15000 AND color = black) ', 1)
UNION
SELECT get_saved_search_id('EXISTS(SLECT car_id FROM Car WHERE type=3 AND price <= 20000 AND color = white)', 2)
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially do it by using a CROSS JOIN and generating a humongous WHERE/OR clause (instead of your EXISTS), with one condition for each saved_search_id, as follows:

```
SELECT saved_search_id,
       visitor_id,
       car_id
FROM   searches a
CROSS JOIN cars b
-- generated WHERE clause below based on saved_search_id + search_url column
WHERE (saved_search_id = 0 AND type = 0 AND price <= 10000 AND color = 'red')
OR (saved_search_id = 1 AND type = 2 AND price <= 15000 AND color = 'black')
OR (saved_search_id = 2 AND type = 3 AND price <= 20000 AND color = 'white')
```

EDIT: add in a filter on inserted car id (10, for example)

```
SELECT saved_search_id,
       visitor_id,
       car_id
FROM   searches a
CROSS JOIN cars b
-- generated WHERE clause below based on saved_search_id + search_url column
WHERE (
(saved_search_id = 0 AND type = 0 AND price <= 10000 AND color = 'red')
OR (saved_search_id = 1 AND type = 2 AND price <= 15000 AND color = 'black')
OR (saved_search_id = 2 AND type = 3 AND price <= 20000 AND color = 'white')
) 
AND car_id = 10  --<-- inserted car id
```

Comment: don't you think that the inserted car id has something to do with the query (AND car_id = 10) (If last inserted ID = 10)

Comment: The cartesian join and the search restrictions mean you will retrieve all car ids that match the criteria, so you get the related search id, visitor id and car ids.  (I went so far as to test this on a DBfiddle). Assuming you know the inserted car id, you can then simply add that additional filter to the returned results i.e. add an `AND car_id = inserted_car_id` clause after bracketing the entire set of OR conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The dealer inserts a new car with particular @type, @price, and @color. Use these parameters to find the related searches:

```
select *
from searches
where search_url like concat('type=', @type, '%color=', @color)
and cast(substring_index(search_url, '&price_max=', -1) as int) >= @price;
```

(Casting to integer in MySQL takes the number only and ignores the rest of the string.)

And if you want to use the already inserted car row instead:

```
select *
from searches s
where exists
(
  select null
  from cars c
  where c.id = 12345 -- the inserted row's ID
  and s.search_url like concat('type=', c.type, '%color=', c.color)
  and cast(substring_index(s.search_url, '&price_max=', -1) as int) >= c.price
);
```

Of course you can also write a function for this accepting the search string and the car parameters - or the car ID for an already inserted car row. With the latter you'd have something like:

```
select *
from searches s
where search_matches_car(s.search_url, 12345);
```

The same with a join for the case you want to see car information, too:

```
select *
from cars c
join searches s on search_matches_car(s.search_url, c.id)
where c.id = 12345;
```